# How to turn off proc's display?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Each time my passive ability proc's, giving my other ability an bonus I can see auras on my display. For example, such an aura for frost death knight you can see on the picture. [image: picture]

Sometimes it is quite annoying, because you can't use middle of the screen for more useful and compact information. How can you turn off this visual effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the option for this under Interface - Combat - Show Spell Alerts:

[image]

Comment: I know this is an old question, but does anyone know if this option existed in WOTLK 3.3.5a and if so, where it is located? I actually would like to turn it on if it existed